# Is it right to say that store is the model?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, model-view-controller, flux, mobx

I feel that the MVC pattern and its derivatives (MVVM, MVP, MVW..) is sort of dead. A new pattern is born: The state management pattern (flux, mobx...).

Well, after learning these patterns, it seems that they're not so different, component is VM, state is Model and that's it.

Am I right?

- If Yes, why do we need to rename that entities (store instead of model), IMO it makes it more complicated to understand the new concept, because we (me) search for a big difference which confirms that everything must be renamed...
- If I wrong, please help me understand where are the differences? I mean it must have a huge difference to rename the whole concept...

Thank you

Comment: yeah, basically they are comparable, you're moving the controller role into the view component (for validating/conditioning) and state handlers (reducers as methods)

Comment: Ok so I'm not totally wrong? (Why down vote? - I updated my question)

Comment: i've never downvoted anyone. the question is somewhat subjective and hard to give an exact technical answer to. MVC is far from dead, despite the latest buzzword-driven frameworks.

Comment: Question is maybe subjective, that because people ( me ), are using (and knowing) a concept, then some other people tell them: _forget all you know It's not as good as your think_. I'm happy when I learn new things, but I feel like I don't understand the NEW concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider *DOM* as `View`, *components/VirtualDOM* as `ViewModel`, *store* as `Model`, well, imo it is `MVVM`. So I think you are not wrong. Actually, in my project, I name my global MobX stores as `Store`, and name my local MobX stores(that are working for certain components) as `Model`. (If there are better naming pratice, please tell me)

At the same time, the state management pattern is quite different from `MVVM/MVC/MVW`.

- **Data in Model**: You can save user settings like preferred languages or themes in stores, so that your stores are different from traditional `Model`, which is supposed to deal with business logic and data.
- **Amount of Model**: If you use Redux or Hyperapp or sth like them, there is only one global state tree. So it is quite different from traditional ways in which you create a lot of `Model` objects.
- **Component-Driven**: You do not need to handle everything. You can just import a component which is created by others and simply pass data to it. Then it will deal with user interactions and update the view by itself. Maybe it contains a `Controller`, maybe it contains a `Model`, maybe it contains none of them. It doesn't matter. You simply don't care.
- **Snapshot**: You can take a snapshot of your state and save it as a string. Next time you can just parse the string and restore all the website/system. Just like save/load of an electronic game. This is a principal of the state management pattern. While traditional `MVVM/MVW` ways does not force you to do that. (And also I think it is quite difficult for traditional ways to do that, perhaps impossible)
- **Immutable**: Take React for example, you have a state and a virtual-dom tree, you do not change them, you generate a new state and a new tree to replace the old ones. You should be aware of the life circles of the tree and know how to generate a new tree efficiently. It is obviously different from traditional `MVVM/MVW` ways.

So I think it is not a bad idea to name entities like components or stores in a new way. If you name them in old ways, maybe programmers will code in old ways, and as a result they will not enjoy the full power of modern frameworks.